# aptitude install imapsync does not work anymore

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, imap

There is a tutorial I used to install `imapsync`, but now when I run this command:

```
aptitude install imapsync
```

I get this error message:

```
Couldn't find any package matching "imapsync".  However, the following
packages contain "imapsync" in their description:
  imapcopy imapcopy:i386 
Couldn't find any package matching "imapsync".  However, the following
packages contain "imapsync" in their description:
  imapcopy imapcopy:i386 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

The command used to word. So why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

The package `imapsync` is not in the repositories anymore. You can use [`imapcopy`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/imapcopy.1.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it worked before? According to its wiki.ubuntuusers page its not in the repos since 11.10?

Whatever, in order to build it:

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts debhelper cdbs libdigest-hmac-perl libterm-readkey-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libdate-manip-perl libmail-imapclient-perl
```

Create tmp directory:

```
mkdir ~/tmp; cd ~/tmp
```

download:sources

```
dget -xu http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20100707T160604Z/pool/main/i/imapsync/imapsync_1.315%2Bdfsg-1.dsc 
cd imapsync-1.315+dfsg
```

modify: add `rebuild` after asteriks * on line 3:

```
dch -l +local 
* rebuild
```

compile:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

and install:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../imapsync_1.315+dfsg-1+local1_all.deb
apt-get -f install
```

This works on Ubuntu 14.10. Reference:http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/imapsync (german)